# Can anyone please help me to achave Mouse Gesture/Draw in ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: mouse, gestures

I was very dependent on mouse gestures on my windows system, however I recently switched to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I am loving it, but the only thing I am missing badly is ***strokePlus*** mouse gestures here I've tried installing **easyStroke** but it is not working ("not able to record or run gestures"), Can anyone please help me to get mouse/draw gestures here. It will be very appriciated. Thanks

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Touchegg 

not that I could get it working a few years ago when I last tried , but that was HP, I am now ASUS, Ryzen AMD's.